# Get last five years values array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[{ label: "2022", value: "2022" }, {label: "2021", value: "2021"},{label: "2020", value: "2020"}, {label: "2019", value: "2019"}]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Its a little bit unclear

Comment: Please follow the guidelines for asking questions on stackoverflow. Otherwise, it is hard to make sense of the question and give any sensible answer

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the current year with [`new Date().getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).

Now, you need to generate an array and modify it:

- Use the [Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) with the `arrayLength` parameter, to generate an array with a specific length
- Prefill the array with the current year using the [`fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method
- Using the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, subtract with the index to count the years downwards
- Using the map method again, convert the year to string and finally to the object in the desired format

Result:

```js
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const result = new Array(5)
  .fill(currentYear)
  .map((year, i) => year - i)
  .map(year => year.toString())
  .map(stringifiedYear => ({ value: stringifiedYear, label: stringifiedYear }));
console.log(result);
```